# Prove that $min\{\|x-y\|:y\in M\}=max\{|\langle x,y\rangle|:y\in M^\perp , \|y\|=1\}$

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products

> Suppose $M$ is a closed subspace of a Hilbert space $X$. Let $x\in X$. Prove that $min\{\|x-y\|:y\in M\}=max\{|\langle x,y\rangle|:y\in M^\perp , \|y\|=1\}$

My Try:

First of all I am confused how one can mention max instead of sup (min case was figured out already). I really appreciate If somebody can explain it.

Secondly, If we forget it, I can consider $2$ cases.

Case I: $x\in M$. Then both are $0$ and hence the result.

Case II: $x\notin M$. this is the case where I am stuck.

By Hahn Banach theorem there is a bounded linear functional $L$ on $X$ such that $L(m)=0$ for all $m\in M$, $L(x)=1$ and $\|L\|=\frac{1}{A}$ where $A=min\{\|x-y\||y\in M\}$.

By another theorem we have there is a unique $y_1\in X$ such that $Lx_1=\langle x_1,y_1\rangle $ for all $x_1\in X$ and $\|L\|=\|y_1\|$. Hence, $Lm=\langle m,y_1\rangle=0$. So, $y_1\in M^\perp$.

Now how can I proceed? can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Call $Px$ the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $M$, then it's easy to see that $\| x-Px\|= \inf_{y\in M}\| x-y\|$. On the other hand we have that $\max_{y\in M^\perp, \| y\|=1} |\langle x,y\rangle|$ is just the norm of the linear functional $l(y)=\langle x,y\rangle $ when viewed as $l\colon M^\perp \to \mathbb{C}$. Since $Px \perp  M^\perp$ we have that
$$
\langle x,y \rangle = \langle x-Px, y\rangle \leq \| x-Px\| \|y\|,\qquad y\in M^\perp,
$$ 
so that $\| l\| \leq \| x-Px\|$. On the other hand, since $x-Px\in M^\perp$ we get that $\| l\| =\|x-Px\|$ and this is what you want.

Edit: A more streamlined approach. 
$$
\langle x,y \rangle =\langle x-Px, y\rangle, \qquad y\in M^\perp.
$$
By Cauchy-Schwarz this last is bounded above by $\| x-Px\| $ whenever $\| y\|=1$ and attains equality in $x-Px$. Therefore this $\sup$ is attained and it equals the $\min$.

Comment: More explicity, if $y \in M$, then $$||x-y||^2 = ||x-Px+Px-y||^2 = ||x-Px||^2+||Px-y||^2 \geq ||x-Px||^2$$which shows that $||x-Px|| = \inf_{y\in M} ||x-y||$.

Comment: Can you please explain why we have max here instead of sup? Is it just because the inner product is bounded and continuous?

Comment: You can check that the argument I gave shows that the $\sup$ is attained at $y=x-Px$.

Comment: @Jose27: How do you get that $l$ is a real valued functional? Because $X$ can be a complex Hilbert Space. Also, because of this reason, $l$ is not linear.

Comment: I think here it suffices to consider the set $\{|\langle x,y\rangle|:y\in M^\perp, \|y\|=1\}$ and use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. No need to take such $l$.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta: It doesn't actually matter (you can switch the variables since your condition only involves the modulus of the inner product, which is unchanged if we switch).

Comment: @Jose27: How is the $\min \leq \max$ direction established exactly?